# Creating a linear actuator

Tags: stepper-motor, diy, actuator

so I am working on a project that involves opening and closing a two piece chamber made of rubber. I have to get a good seal on the chamber so no gases can pass through between the rubber pieces and have gone with the choice of using a linear actuator for the opening and closing motions similar to the picture shown below, but the problem is that the motor for this actuator is too weak and I need more torque, and high torque versions of these are about $30-$40 which I would rather not spend because I would have to get 3 or 4. But I already have some high torque steppers by themselves and thought that it would probably only be a few extra steps to convert it into an actuator. So my question is basically where would I start to get the basic up and down motion? Can I just take a lead screw and weld it on the motor? Or are there more steps in the process, if I do end up welding would I have to watch out for the temperature because it may mess with the coils inside?

thanks a lot for the help!

[image]

Comment: You certainly should not weld a linear screw of any type directly to a stepper motor shaft. You can buy linear threads/nuts in a variety of types and use a coupling to join to the stepper shaft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motor and screw are two separate units, they are not welded together. You may not, and probably you can not weld the shafts together. A common practice is to use a shaft coupling.

[image]